# Installing sqlsrv on PHP 5.5.15 XAMMP won't appear in the PHP Info

Tags: php, xampp

I am new to this type of thing and am getting most frustrated (As all newbies do lol)

I am trying to install the sqlsrv extension into the PHP on my XAMMP server to test some PHP to SQL database form submissions.

The first issue I have come across this that our friends at microsoft have not bothered to write sqlsrv drivers for PHP 5.5.15 at all. I have however managed to isolate the drivers recompiled for 5.5.15 by someone else. Now obviously these are unofficial but people claim they work fine.

I have put these dll files in the "ext" folder

php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll

php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll

php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

and added the file names to the php.ini at the end of the "Windows Extensions" list.

When I start up my XAMMP Server it starts fine but when I click on PHP info section they do not appear as they apparently should there.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need sqlsrv? You can use mysql/mysqli extensions to communicate with MySQL which can be accessed via phpMyAdmin in XAMPP. Or you can use PDO to connect to other kinds of Databses like PostgreSQL, MSSQL, etc.

Comment: I need to be able to use SQL Server Management Studio with the updated database so can't use MySQL ....or so my research tells me. I understand that there are other databases that can be assessed but I'm not keen on using them as sql server is what I am familiar with.

Comment: @MattLuka : Please check my [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/816939/microsoft-php-sql-server-drivers-not-working-cant-load-module/816968#816968) also

Comment: From where can i download those dll files?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try editing php.ini and adding this code?

**For the non thread safe version of PHP:**

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
```

**For the thread safe version of PHP:**

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll   
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```